# Java NIO2 - Return a recursive Collection<Path>

Tags: java, recursion, java-7, java.nio.file

I am looking at the new functionality in Java7.  I want to get a Collection objects returned given a specific input directory.

Currently I am using using (org.apache.commons.io)

```
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(myInputFile, ...);
```

Instead I would like to do something like:

```
Collection<Path> paths = listPathsUsingJava7(myInputPath, ...);
```

However, I don't see anything specific about doing it in the examples/docs out there.  I see DirectoryStreams, which don't seem to do recursion.  I also see Vistors which make you take action on the current object instead of adding it to a Collection.

Does anyone have a Java7 example of doing this the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

next JDK7 code will add all files in folder and subfolders to `files`.

```
    final List<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(myInputPath), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            files.add(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Is there also a way to filter the input directory based on a glob?  Or do you have to loop through a list in the preVisitDirectory method?

Comment: yep, you can use `preVisitDirectory`. Declare glob matcher `final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/nbproject");` and use it in preVisit: `public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                return matcher.matches(dir) ? FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE : FileVisitResult.CONTINUE ;
            }`